# How do I create a type alias for a function returning a struct with two lifetimes?

Tags: function, types, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to pass a custom function as a parameter. This function has as the only argument a custom struct and returns a struct of the same type. The goal is to have a function that can passed around that may or may not have input arguments and may or may not return a value.

```
pub type MyFunction = fn(Option<&MyStruct>) -> Option<MyStruct>;

pub trait DynamicTrait {
    fn typename(&self) -> &str {}
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    types: Vec<String>,
    vars: Vec<Box<DynamicTrait>>,
}
```

When compiling, it gives the following error.

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:1:55
  |
1 | pub type MyFunction = fn(Option<&MyStruct>) -> Option<MyStruct>;
  |                                                       ^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
  |
  = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say which one of argument 1's 2 lifetimes it is borrowed from
```

I've tried changing it to:

```
pub type MyFunction = &Fn<'e>(Option<&MyStruct>) -> Option<MyStruct<'e>>;
```

Which fails with this error:

```
error: expected one of `!`, `::`, or `;`, found `(`
 --> src/main.rs:1:30
  |
1 | pub type MyFunction = &Fn<'e>(Option<&MyStruct>) -> Option<MyStruct<'e>>;
  |                              ^ expected one of `!`, `::`, or `;` here
```

And to this:

```
pub type MyFunction = fn<'e>(Option<&MyStruct>) -> Option<MyStruct<'e>>;
```

Which yields this other error:

```
error: expected `(`, found `<`
 --> src/main.rs:1:25
  |
1 | pub type MyFunction = fn<'e>(Option<&MyStruct>) -> Option<MyStruct<'e>>;
  |                         ^
```

I don't know if the error has to do with how lifetimes are managed or how I defined the struct/function or something completely different.

I'm using Rust 1.23.0.

Comment: `pub type MyFunction<'e> = fn(Option<&MyStruct>) -> Option<MyStruct<'e>>;` or `pub type MyFunction<'e> = fn(Option<&'e MyStruct<'e>>) -> Option<MyStruct<'e>>;` or whatever the lifetimes should be.